# how to change jquery ui selectmenu to listbox?

Tags: jquery, select-menu

I'm currently working in jQuery UI Selectmenu. i want to change select to listbox inside icon for each option.

i tried to add maxheight and size attribute inside the select tag. is there anyway we can change jquery ui selectmenu to listbox?